# In C: assigning variables when reading in a one-line text file

Tags: c, perl

I'm a beginning programmer. I've been learning C, Fortran, and Perl in a hurry. I have a goal of creating a webpage containing a surface plot. I am able to make my programs communicate to get this done, but have a problem with the assignment of my variables in my C program.

From my Perl program, I get a text file, `data.in` which only contains one line.

For example: `cosxtsiny 50 0.5 3 0 6`. This is what I've done:

(declared my variables as `char`, `int`, or `double`)

```
FILE *fi

fi = open("data.in", "r");
fscanf(fi, "%s %d %f %f %f %f", &func, &PTS, &xxa, &xxb, &yyc, &yyd);

close(fi);
```

I'm supposed to produce a file, `data.out`, with the values I get from `data.in` once I do some calculations with it. These will later produce the surface plot for me.

Here is my problem: I do get a surface plot with the correct amount of gridpionts (PTS) so I know the first two assignments are right, but my axes are off. When I see my `data.out`, my axes don't start and end where they are supposed to. Any suggestions?

Comment: Move the axes until they start and end where they're supposed to.

Comment: Declared your declarations as useless... Please post *real* code; this stuff is unreadable.

Comment: The declaration of `func` is crucial; you must show what you've written, because the chances are that what you've written is not what you should have written.  Most likely, either the declaration is incorrect or the call to `fscanf()` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you are declaring `func` as a character array, then you should write something like `fscanf(fi, "%s", func)` instead of `fscanf(fi,"%s", &func)`.

Comment: func is to just contain a string which is the first thing on the line that I'm reading so it's not really an array.

i declared func as: char func. maybe I'm getting confused as to declaring a variable to contain a string.

Comment: @RosaLemus: How do you declare "func" then?

Comment: i have: double xxa, xxb, yyc, yyd; char func; FILE *fi;

Comment: @RosaLemus: How can you read a string when func is defined as a character only?

Comment: how should i define it, if i want it to contain a string?

Comment: @RosaLemus: You should define it in the form of a character array, like char func[100], here 100 means the array can take up to 100 characters, but since in C++, the ending of a character array is '\0', which is also a character, so char func[100] has a maximum length of 99. Change the number "100" according to the requirements of your program.

Comment: so this is how i have it now, char func[5]. then fscanf(fi, "%s", func[5]);

Comment: @RosaLemus: fscanf(fi,"%s",func) would suffice since we only need to know the address of the first element of the func array, which corresponds to either &func[0] or func.

Comment: If you have `char func[100];` then using plain `func` in the `fscanf()` call is correct (enough - we can argue about names longer than 99 characters, but that probably won't be a problem for you).  Declared as just `char func;`, then you needed the `&`, but you immediately ran into buffer overflows since the data contained 9 characters, so you overshot the end of the allocated space by 9 bytes (including the terminal NUL, `'\0'`).  This would wreak havoc on something - who knows what, or cares, since you were invoking undefined behaviour. You have to be careful with strings in C; very careful!

Comment: my understanding of using fscanf(fi, "&s", func) is that i'll end up with a string containing the whole line in my text file and all these will then be char. only the first part of my line do i need it to be a string, the rest are int or double.

Comment: On its own, `fscanf(fi, "%s", func)` (where I assume you meant `%s` and not `&s`) will skip a bunch of white space (possibly zero characters), then read a 'word' - a set of characters not in the 'isspace()` category - into the string `func`; it will then stop, leaving anything else on the line to be read by the next `fscanf()`.

Comment: @RosaLemus: Jonathan is correct, the reason why we use fscanf(fi,"%s",func) is that scanf / fscanf will read a word till it reaches whitespace characters. You can not read a whole line containinng whitespaces using "%s" alone, you need to use something like gets(str) for that aim.

Comment: Yet, `fscanf` with `%s` + unpredictable string length = possible buffer overflow (prefer `fscanf` + `%#s`, where # is the maximum number of bytes to read). And `gets` + unpredictable string length = possible buffer overflow (prefer `fgets`)

Comment: Thanx Jonathan for the explanation. I set up the read in of the the line with first fscanf(fi, "%s", func); followed by fscanf(fi, "%d", &PTS); then fscanf(fi, "%f "%f", &xxa, &xxb). I thought the the breaking up of the fscanf's would help in reading in the line. I still don't get the values of xxa and xxb to assign appropriately though. I did try fscanf(fi, "%d %f %f", &PTS, &xxa, &xxb) also.

Comment: @RosaLemus: What's the first line of the input?

Answer (score 0):

define an char array `char func[LEN];`  or allocate memory to your char pointer `func = (char *)malloc(NUMBER_OF_BYTES_YOU_WANT);`

also you need to write `scanf("%s", func);` not `&func`;

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and worked fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fpi, *fpo;
    char data[100];
    int pts;
    float xxa, xxb, yyc, yyd;

    fpi = fopen("data.in", "r");

    if (fpi == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to open file - data.in \n");
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf(fpi, "%s %d %f %f %f %f", data, &pts, &xxa, &xxb, &yyc, &yyd);
    fclose(fpi);

    /* do you calculations here */

    fpo = fopen("data.out", "w");

    if (fpi == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to open file - data.out \n");
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(fpo, "%s %d %1.1f %1.1f %1.1f %1.1f\n", data, pts, xxa, xxb, yyc, yyd);
    fclose(fpo);

    return 0;
}
```

and I saw the following output:

```
>
> cat data.in
cosxtsiny 50 0.5 3 0 6
>
> gcc a.c
>
> ./a.out
>
> cat data.out
cosxtsiny 50 0.5 3.0 0.0 6.0
>
```

Note : you can change the `fprintf()` format specifiers (f.e. %1.1f) based the number of decimal points you want to print.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @RosaLemus If you find the above post answers your question, please confirm so by clicking at the tick mark. Thanks!