# How do I read input from file correctly?

Tags: c, file, input

```
INITIALIZE 100  
ALLOC 20  
ALLOC 10  
FREE 16  
ALLOC 19  
FILL 16 19 255  
FILL 48 10 127  
DUMP  
SHOW ALLOCATIONS  
ALLOC 1  
SHOW USAGE  
FINALIZE
```

This is an example of instructions. If I insert them line by line, the programme works. If I read all of them from a file, I get segmentation fault. It is important to read them from input file. Where could the problem be? To clarify, I don't need to read the file in the programme, I need to redirect a file to the standard input. This is how I compare the input with my commands.

int main()

{

```
int n,c,d,e;

char *s, *p, init[100]="INITIALIZE", fin[100]="FINALIZE", dmp[100]="DUMP", allc[100]="ALLOC", fre[100]="FREE", fil[100]="FILL", shw[100]="SHOW", usg[100]="USAGE", alc[100]="ALLOCATIONS";

unsigned char *arena;

s=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

while (1)

{

    gets(s);

    p=strtok(s," ,.-");

    while(p!=NULL)

    {

        if(strcmp(p,init)==0)

        {

            p=strtok(NULL," .,-");

            n=atoi(p);

            arena=initialize(n); 

        }

        if(strcmp(p,fin)==0) { finalize(arena); }

        if(strcmp(p,dmp)==0) { dump(arena,n); }

        if(strcmp(p,allc)==0) 

        {

            p=strtok(NULL," ,.-");

            c=atoi(p); 

            alloc(c,arena,n); 

        }

        if(strcmp(p,fre)==0) 

        { 

            p=strtok(NULL," ,.-");

            c=atoi(p);

            freeb(arena,c); 

        }

        if(strcmp(p,fil)==0) 

        { 

            p=strtok(NULL," ,.-");

            c=atoi(p);      

            p=strtok(NULL," ,.-");

            d=atoi(p);

            p=strtok(NULL," ,.-");

            e=atoi(p);

            fill(arena,c,d,e);

        }

        if(strcmp(p,shw)==0) 

        { 

            p=strtok(NULL," ,.-");

            if(strcmp(p,fre)==0) { showfree(arena,n); }

            if(strcmp(p,usg)==0) { showusage(arena,n); }

            if(strcmp(p,alc)==0) { showallocations(arena,n); }

        }

        p=strtok(NULL," ,.-");

    }

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: No code and you want us to look for your errors? We're not oracles, dude!

Comment: Show your code. And if you want to do a parser in C, take a look at lex/yacc

Comment: I suspect buffer overrun. You don't have enough space for all of the file though you have space for each single line.

Comment: First rule of C programming: *never* use gets.

Answer (score 0):

You could have done a basic search before posting one such question. Anyhow, if you're looking for code-snippets/example-programs to open, read, write and close files using a C program, please take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569444/in-c-assigning-variables-when-reading-in-a-one-line-text-file/8571416#8571416)